# Exception in thread "Thread-11" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-pde

I am using the following code to open an editor in Eclipse.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
             if(true) {
                String filePath = ... ;
                final IFile inputFile = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot().getFileForLocation(Path.fromOSString(filePath));
                IWorkbench wb = PlatformUI.getWorkbench();
                if (wb.getWorkbenchWindowCount() == 1) {
                  try{                
                  if (inputFile != null) {                        
                              try {
                                  IPerspectiveDescriptor perspective = wb.getWorkbenchWindows()[0].getActivePage().getPerspective();
                                  IWorkbenchPage page = wb.getWorkbenchWindows()[0].getActivePage();
                                IEditorPart openEditor = IDE.openEditor(page, inputFile);
                            } catch (PartInitException e) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }                             
                 }                    
                  }
                  catch(NullPointerException e)
                  {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                }
             }}
          
       }).start();
```

Which keeps returning the `org.eclipse.swt.SWTException` exception

```
Exception in thread "Thread-14" org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Invalid thread access
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4723)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4638)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4609)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.error(Display.java:1105)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.createDisplay(Display.java:853)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.create(Display.java:837)
at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Device.<init>(Device.java:132)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:736)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.<init>(Display.java:727)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.getDefault(Display.java:1439)
```

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: `Display.getDefault()` is trying to create a new display - it should not be trying to do this in an Eclipse plug-in. So is this running in a plug-in or something else? These Eclipse APIs will only work in a plug-in.

Comment: Yes it is running in a plugin

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how Display.getDefault could possibly be trying to create a display in that case. The main Eclipse code creates the display and plug-ins just use that.

Comment: I got you. I updated my code.

Comment: Most of the APIs you are using expect to run in the UI thread so I don’t think this code is correct at all. If you want to delay use Display.timerExec rather than a thread

Comment: I am not really interested in delaying, I get rid of this line. 
This code is invoked from a graphical editor that I created, which runs in an Eclipse application. While the plugin containing this code is imported in the workspace of the main eclipse instance.

Comment: This 'Eclipse application' is an Eclipse RCP? As I said Display.getDefault should never give this error if it is run as part of a plug-in running in Ecliipse or an Eclipse RCP. It will definitely give this error running in a background thread in an application that has not set up a Display.